# node.js TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

Given below Node.js code i was try to use https as the project required but getting error

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"

```
const express = require("express");
var https = require("https");


const app = express();


app.get("/", function(req, res) {

    const url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Gwalior&appid=4b01458a2b74d57ff37f136f382ac4d5&units=metric";

    https.get(url, function(response) {
        console.log(response.statusCode)
    });
    res.send("Server is Up and Running");
})



app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000.");
})
```

Complete Error stack trace:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:151:11)
    at request (https.js:316:10)
    at Object.get (https.js:320:15)
    at C:\Users\Public\Documents\WeatherProject\app.js:12:10
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Public\Documents\WeatherProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Public\Documents\WeatherProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Public\Documents\WeatherProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Public\Documents\WeatherProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Public\Documents\WeatherProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Public\Documents\WeatherProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

But if i am using http its working fine even i have tried with
node install https (still not work)

Comment: Your ``url`` variable starts with ``http://``.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the code is that you are making https request and in your url you are using `"http"` instead of `"https"`. So if you change your url to `"https"` it should work.

`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Gwalior&appid=4b01458a2b74d57ff37f136f382ac4d5&units=metric`

I know you have figured this out but for the purpose of those that might run into this in the future - So the code should be:

```js
const express = require("express");
var https = require("https");


const app = express();


app.get("/", function(req, res) {

    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Gwalior&appid=4b01458a2b74d57ff37f136f382ac4d5&units=metric";

    https.get(url, function(response) {
        console.log(response.statusCode)
    });
    res.send("Server is Up and Running");
})



app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000.");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your doing https request and your url starts with `http://` when it should be `https://`.