# 'TypeError: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"' error when fetching HTTPS site

Tags: http, ssl, https, fetch, node-fetch

I'm trying to use node-fetch to capture the contents of a page, and running into an unexpected error. I checked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469923/node-js-typeerror-err-invalid-protocol-protocol-http-not-supported-expect) but it doesn't seem relevant.  I am trying to fetch a HTTPS site using an HTTPS agent and agents, but I'm getting an unexpected error about HTTP. I wonder whether this may be due to redirects, but I can't see anything that would cause it. This only fails for this particular URL (works fine, for example, with https://www.robinhood.com) , and I'm trying to figure out why. Here is a minimal example. I'd note that this uses some certificates I have saved locally, but I'm not sure how necessary that is to reproduce.

```
//start SO example
var siteURL = "https://robinhood.com/l/privacy";
import path from 'path';
import sslrootcas from 'ssl-root-cas';
const rootCas = sslrootcas.create();
import {fileURLToPath} from 'url';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
rootCas.addFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'intermediate.pem'));
import http from 'node:http';
import https from 'node:https';
import UserAgent       from 'user-agents';  
const myhttpsAgent = new https.Agent({ca: rootCas});
// const requestcheck =  fetch("https://www.google.com", {
const requestcheck =  fetch(siteURL, {
   method: "GET"
  ,headers: {"User-Agent":  new UserAgent() }
  ,agent: myhttpsAgent
  })
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
node:internal/errors:477
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at new ClientRequest (node:_http_client:177:11)
    at request (node:http:96:10)
    at file:///home/app/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:94:20
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at fetch (file:///home/app/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:49:9)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///home/app/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:236:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:674:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:521:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder whether this may be due to redirects, **but I can't see anything that would cause it.**

`https://robinhood.com/l/privacy` redirects to
`https://robinhood.com/us/en/support/articles/privacy-policy` which then redirects to
`http://robinhood.com/us/en/support/articles/privacy-policy/`

The latter URL is plain HTTP and thus the wrong protocol by a https-only user agent.

Comment: It's weird, I don't see that last redirect when I look in the Network tab in Developer Tools on Firefox. Maybe it isn't redirecting on Firefox for some reason. Is there some way to switch the agent in that case?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the http(s).Agent section in the documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch and think I've been able to get it to work. Thank you!